# mask-image with linear-gradient on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, mask

The following snippet perfectly works on Chrome: the background image fades into to the background behind towards the bottom.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/wcDxIZG.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(black, black, transparent);
  mask-image: linear-gradient(black, black, transparent);
}
```

```html
  <div></div>
```

But it doesn't work on Firefox, the value is said to be incorrect.

Why ? And how can I fix that ?

*Note that I know how to use another div as overlay, which isn't a general solution to me as it has too many consequences on content and element `position`. The only answers I'm interested in are the ones which fix the background of the div.*

Comment: As [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=mask-image) saying, you cannot avoid SVG in all versions of Firefox.

Comment: Part of the problem is Firefox isn't often up to date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Firefox 53 (released April 19, 2017) , this is now possible as the support of masking images has been completed.

See http://caniuse.com/#search=mask

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but you can replicate the effect by using the `:after` property for this, and this works for all browsers - even our old friend IE:

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/wcDxIZG.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.image:after {
  content: '';
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0, startColorstr='#FAFAFA', endColorstr='#FAFAFA');
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(248, 244, 243, 0) 0%, #fafafa 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(248, 244, 243, 0) 0%, #fafafa 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(2248, 244, 243, 0) 0%, #fafafa 100%);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-event: none;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is my current workaround for some trivial cases but this doesn't really replicate, as it also covers all the content (which means you have to use a bunch of other divs)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in safari, though works in chrome and firefox.